# How to I get rid of warning messages fo OCX's for an unverified publisher?

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic, internet-explorer-9, ocx

I have a classic ASP application with downloads and installs several custom OCX files.

I keep getting a message that reads:

```
 This web page wants to run the following add-on: 'name.ocx' 
 from 'my name (unverified publisher)'
```

Given that I'm running these web applications in-house and I don't want to go through the hassle of becoming a Verified Publisher for this legacy application; how can stop the messages from popping up on my users Internet Explorer the first time that they are download and installed?

Note: The website for this application is in my Trusted Zone - and I've enabled basically everything in the Active X settings for the Trusted Zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the settings for the Trusted Zone; make sure that the "Only allow approved domains to use ActiveX without prompt" option has been set to disabled. Microsoft seems to have reversed the pattern with "what is the most permissive option" for that entry.